# retrofit fetching data from local storage in android studio

Tags: java, android-studio, retrofit2

I need to save last api results in my app if the user open the app without network connection , then he will see last data fethed from the server , i need to fetch json as string and parse json to objects from string by using retrofit library in android studio

Answer (score 0):

Refer about  :https://medium.com/@prabuddafernando_53470/mvvm-architecture-viewmodel-and-livedata-f28c0d20300b

what you can do is check the internet on repository, it not connected fetch the data from local share preference, if its too much data use room persistence database for the data saving. in the repository can call two way of option 1. Is from remote repository 2. is from remote repository. hence you can get the data from local repo if the internet is not available.

Comment: link not open !